# Insert query with a subquery

Tags: sql-server, insert, subquery

I want to insert somewhere around 400 rows into a table. All of the column values will be the same fixed value for most of the columns, with exception to one column which I want to pull from a fairly complicated subquery that will pull over 400 unique values from another table using a series of joins and where statements. We attempted the following query:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES(val1, (subquery), val2, val3)
```

It stated, that it wouldn't work because the subquery yielded more than one result. The only values being pulled from a different table is in the subquery. I cannot insert the subquery into the respective column by itself, since col1 is a NOT NULL column.

Comment: Is the question for SQL-Server or some other DBMS?

Comment: The database is telling you the problem. If your subquery yields more than one row, how can the database insert it in a single row ? You should specify a query that yields only one row for each inserted row.

Answer (score 3):

If the `(subquery)` has `SELECT (whatever expression) AS col FROM ...`, then you can do:

```
INSERT INTO mytable 
  (col1, col2, col3, col4) 
SELECT 
  val1, s.col, val2, val3
FROM 
  (subquery) AS s ;
```

or:

```
WITH s (col) AS
  (subquery)
INSERT INTO mytable 
  (col1, col2, col3, col4) 
SELECT 
  val1, s.col, val2, val3
FROM 
  s ;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for what I wanted to do. I'm new to database management so your info will help me out on a lot of the stuff I need to do.

Answer (score 3):

Simple , just try to adapt the following code

```
insert into prices (group, id, price)
select 
    7, articleId, 1.50
from article where name like 'ABC%';
```